# Can't bind Dynamically created GridView based on Dynamically populated DropDownList selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been struggling to find a solution to this, but still nothing good.

I create a GridView from code behind (as well as the SqlDataSource). In my page there is a DropDownList filled with usernames (populated in code behind).

When I select an username in the DDL, the GridView is supposed to rebind and show only the data belonging to that specific user. For some reason I can't make it work and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

**Creation of GW and SqlDS:**

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr = new SqlDataSource();
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ID = "SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr);
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectCommand = "Query";
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Add("userID", DropDownListUtenti.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
            GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataSource = SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr;
            GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
```

**SelectedIndex method:**

```
    protected void DropDownListUtenti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is you writing in page_load. are you checking !Page.IsPostBack on load

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
{
        populateGrid();
}

I have this in my Page_Load, I call the method to create the GW and SqlDS.

Comment: befor populating the DDL you must check Page.IsPostBack. Please check

Comment: please write your Page load code here

Comment: protected void DropDownListUtenti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateGrid(); 
}

Comment: i think you pin point the exact issue jitendra

Comment: @JitendraSawant I tried what you posted. It works only for the first selection..from the second one I get this exception: "The variable name '@userID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to know you found a workaround.
Based on code in your question, making following changes will work for you:

`SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Clear();` will clear the parameters you previously added

**Creation of GW and SqlDS:**

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ID = "SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr);
        SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectCommand = "Query";
        SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Add("userID", DropDownListUtenti.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
        GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataSource = SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr;
        GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Clear();
```

**SelectedIndex method:**

```
   protected void DropDownListUtenti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateGrid();
}
```

Additionally you would like to add :

```
SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

before

```
SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectCommand = "Query";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, maybe not the safest or best, but it works.
I removed the parameters from the SqlDS and inserted the DropDownList selection directly in the query (I wrote a simple example now), as follows:

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr = new SqlDataSource();
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ID = "SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr);
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userID = " + DropDownListUtenti.SelectedValue + "";
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
            GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataSource = SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr;
            GridViewFormulariDaAppr.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need something like this:

```
Parameter param = new Parameter("userID", DbType.String, DropDownListUtenti.SelectedValue);
        if (SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Contains(param))
        {
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters["userID"] = DropDownListUtenti.SelectedValue;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSourceFormulariDaAppr.SelectParameters.Add(param);
        }
```